# lauch c# app from c++ without taskbar button

Tags: c#, c++, taskbar

I am looking for a way to launch a c# app from a c++ app without showing a taskbar button for the c# app until I choose to show it.

I have a class that can hide and show a taskbar button, however the taskbar button shows up very briefly when launching the c# app.

Is there a way to launch a c# app without the os creating a taskbar button, while still allowing me to show a taskbar button later on?

Here is the code Im currently using to hide and show a taskbar button.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var tb = new Taskbar();
        tb.DeleteTab();
        bool hidden = true;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to toggle taskbar button");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            if (hidden)
                tb.AddTab();
            else
                tb.DeleteTab();

            hidden = !hidden;
        }
    }
}

class Taskbar
{
    public void AddTab()
    {
        GetTaskbarList().AddTab(GetMainWindowHandle());
    }

    public void DeleteTab()
    {
        GetTaskbarList().DeleteTab(GetMainWindowHandle());
    }

    ITaskbarList GetTaskbarList()
    {
        var taskbarList = (ITaskbarList)new CoTaskbarList();
        taskbarList.HrInit();
        return taskbarList;
    }

    IntPtr GetMainWindowHandle()
    {
        return Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090")]
    class CoTaskbarList
    {
    }

    [ComImport,
    Guid("56fdf342-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface ITaskbarList
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the taskbar list object. This method must be called before any other ITaskbarList methods can be called.
        /// </summary>
        void HrInit();

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an item to the taskbar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be added to the taskbar.</param>
        void AddTab([In] IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes an item from the taskbar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be deleted from the taskbar.</param>
        void DeleteTab([In] IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Activates an item on the taskbar. The window is not actually activated; the window's item on the taskbar is merely displayed as active.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window on the taskbar to be displayed as active.</param>
        void ActivateTab([In] IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Marks a taskbar item as active but does not visually activate it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be marked as active.</param>
        void SetActiveAlt([In] IntPtr hWnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ShowInTaskbar` ([WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) or [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showintaskbar.aspx)) property.

Set it to `false` initially and the application won't appear.

Set it to `true` when you want the application to appear in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

in your `Form`'s constructor (or setting it in designer, if possible) should ensure that no taskbar button is initially created. I assume that you should still be able to create one when necessary.